# Debug HttpClient request

Tags: http, asp.net-core

How can i see exactly what the request sent by the HttpClient will contain?

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
            new
            {
                merchantId = _merchantId,
                amount = _amount,
                paymentRef = _paymentRef,
                customer_ref = _customer_ref,
                successUrl = _successUrl,
                error_url = _error_url,
                currency = _currency,
                hash = "fsdfsdfsdf"

            });

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(postData));
```

Comment: Fiddler can be used to see exactly what is being sent. Use the filters so that you are not bombarded with all kind of request. Also turn on decryption for SSL traffic if the site is secured.